# MySQL SUM in different ways

Tags: mysql, sum

I have two tables

user_raters:

```
| id(int) | to_id(int) | value(int) | created_at(datetime)
|1        | 2          | 1          | 2009-03-01 00:00:00
```

**EDIT: I changed the user_rater_id.  history_user_raters.user_rater_id is related to user_raters.id**

history_user_raters:

```
| id(int) | user_rater_id(int) | value(int) | created_at(datetime)
| 1       | 1                  | 1          | 2009-03-02 00:00:00
| 2       | 1                  | 1          | 2009-03-02 00:00:00
| 3       | 1                  | -1         | 2009-03-02 00:00:00
| 4       | 1                  | 1          | 2009-03-03 00:00:00
| 5       | 1                  | -1         | 2009-03-03 00:00:00
| 6       | 1                  | -1         | 2009-03-03 00:00:00
| 7       | 1                  | -1         | 2009-03-03 00:00:00
```

I want to count the sum of the values from history_user_raters as it relates to the to_id from user_raters.  The result from the query should be:

```
| year | month | day | total | down | up
| 2009 | 3     | 2   | 1     | 1    | 2
| 2009 | 3     | 3   | -2    | 3    | 1
```

I have a query that is close, but it is not counting the up and down correctly.  The total is right.  Can some one help me write the query or new query that calculates correct up and down?

My current query:

```
SELECT 
 YEAR(history.created_at) AS `year`,
 MONTH(history.created_at) AS `month`,
 DAY(history.created_at) AS `day`,
 SUM(history.value) as `total`,

 (SELECT 
  abs(SUM(historydown.value)) 
 FROM `user_raters` as raterdown 
  INNER JOIN `history_user_raters` AS historydown 
 WHERE raterdown.to_id = 2 
  AND historydown.value = -1 
  AND date(historydown.created_at) 
 GROUP BY history.created_at) as down,

 (SELECT SUM(historyup.value) 
 FROM `user_raters` as raterup 
  INNER JOIN `history_user_raters` AS historyup 
 WHERE raterup.to_id = 2 
  AND historyup.value = 1  
  AND date(history.created_at) 
 GROUP BY raterup.to_id) as up 

FROM `user_raters` 
 INNER JOIN history_user_raters AS history ON user_raters.id = history.user_rater_id
WHERE (user_raters.to_id = 2) 
GROUP BY DATE(history.created_at)
```

Comment: The `USER_RATER.to_id` column relates to what in the `HISTORY_USER_RATERS` table - `id`?

Comment: Sorry.  No to a user table with an id = id. Does that matter for this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might see it too simply (and sorry I can't test with data at the moment), but I'm guessing the following trick with two CASE statements would do just what is needed

```
SELECT 
  YEAR(history.created_at) AS year,
  MONTH(history.created_at) AS month,
  DAY(history.created_at) AS day,
  SUM(history.value) as total,
  SUM(CASE WHEN history.value < 0 THEN history.value ELSE 0 END) as down,
  SUM(CASE WHEN history.value > 0 THEN history.value ELSE 0 END) as up
FROM `user_raters` 
INNER JOIN `history_user_raters` AS history
  ON user_raters.id = history.user_rater_id
WHERE (user_raters.to_id = 1)  -- or some other condition...
GROUP BY DATE(history.created_at)
```

Comment: I am trying to get this working:

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'THEN history.value ELSE 0 END) as down,
  SUM(CASE history.value > 0 THEN histor' at line 6

Comment: @mediaslave My bad... I had forgotten the `WHEN` after the CASE, since we are using a comparison. Should work now...

Comment: Hey thanks for the help, but still an error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM `user_raters`
INNER JOIN `history_user_raters` AS history
  ON user_raters' at line 8

Comment: Dang, another typo...  the extra comma after "... as up".  I just fixed it.  Again, sorry for not being able to test...  Pls try again...

Comment: Thanks, that did it and the query is so much smaller.  I think I was just making it more complicated than it needed to be.

Comment: @mjv user_raters.to_id in the where should = 1 by the way.  Can you edit for future knowledge.  I can't edit posts yet.

Comment: @mediaslave, I changed to 1; btw I got the 2 from the original query, in the question.  Also, you may consider adding the to_id in the group by query, to get all raters's history at once (or some some of them with some filter in the where clause)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: @OMG Ponies deleted his answer.  This response make no sense now, but I am not going to delete my answer, because I think it is silly.**

@OMG ponies

Your query runs, but it returns no results. I had to adjust it a bit to add the to_id in the main queries where clause

```
SELECT 
 YEAR( t.created_at ) AS `year` , 
 MONTH( t.created_at ) AS `month` , 
 DAY( t.created_at ) AS `day` , 
 SUM( t.value ) AS `total` , 
 MAX( COALESCE( x.sum_down, 0 ) ) AS down, 
 MAX( COALESCE( y.sum_up, 0 ) ) AS up
FROM history_user_raters AS t
JOIN user_raters AS ur ON ur.to_id = t.user_rater_id
LEFT JOIN (

 SELECT hur.user_rater_id, 
  SUM( hur.value ) AS sum_down
 FROM history_user_raters AS hur
 WHERE hur.value = -1
 GROUP BY hur.user_rater_id
) AS x ON x.user_rater_id = t.user_rater_id
LEFT JOIN (

 SELECT hur.user_rater_id, 
  SUM( hur.value ) AS sum_up
 FROM history_user_raters AS hur
 WHERE hur.value =1
 GROUP BY hur.user_rater_id
) AS y ON y.user_rater_id = t.user_rater_id
WHERE ur.to_id =1
GROUP BY YEAR( t.created_at ) , MONTH( t.created_at ) , DAY( t.created_at )
```